Is there a way to overload the empty() logic for custom classes on PHP?
Is there a way to overload the empty() logic for custom classes on PHP?
for example:
class X implements Stringable {
    private string $value;
    public function __toString(): string {
        return ''; # not even checking the values, always empty
    }
    # doesn't matter for the obj, only for protected properties, but
    # will not cause error on the private here...
    public function __isset(string $value): bool {
        return false;
    }
}

And a simple test
    public function testXisEmpty(): void {
        $actual = new X();
        $this->assertTrue( empty($actual) );
    }

  ✘ X is empty
   ┐
   ├ Failed asserting that false is true.

Is there any way to make empty() respect the toString value? or is there something like toBool? or isset for the object and not just a field?
Could not find anything on the manual but I also spend a lot of time looking at property overloads before i learned class overloads are called "magic" methods, so I might just be missing the right nomenclature...

Some experts think that using php empty logic is bad practice: https://dev.to/klnjmm/never-use-empty-function-in-php-4pb0

empty in the end does a truthiness test. So the question boils down to: can you change the truthiness (boolean value) of a custom class? To which the answer is: no.

The parameter passed to empty() is not expected to be a string, so when you pass a stringable object to it, there's no way for PHP to know that you intended a string context, and there's no implicit cast performed. So you're basically just checking if the variable has anything in it, which it does -- an instance of an object. If you want to check its string value, you'll have to manually cast it like empty((string) $actual).

@AlexHowansky good points. I did follow the logic up to some point. empty expects/coherces input to a bool. Then the list of things that are coherced to True in a bool type cast does list "a non empty string" before "any object" but on the code they check for Object first :(

No. PHP does not support it.
But you can define interface with your method "isempty" and use it in your classes.
interface IsEmpty {
   function isempty();
}

class YourClass implements IsEmpty {
    function isempty () {
        return false;
    }
}

How do you want to respect the toString value? Maybe you need to use trim() within your implementaion of YourClass .__toString()?

Thanks. will do something along these lines (custom method) but will probably not use the builtin method name :)  I mean, if it is a custom method I can infer more meaning with a specialized name for the use case at hand, instead of the generic builtin.
